# Tessellated space defines a recursive set?

Tags: geometry, first-order-logic, recursion, computability

Is a space which has a regular geometric pattern necessarily a recursive set?

It's obvious, for example, that $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is a recursive set and it has a "regular geometric pattern", so this motivated me to ask is *every* tessellated set recursive.   I don't have a precise definition of a ``tessellated set'' but hopefully it's somewhat clear what I mean.  (I only care about sets with one unique sort of tessellation).

Comment: What do you mean by "recursive set" in this context.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

It actually takes some work to make the ideas in the post precise - keep in mind that equality checking for reals is **not** recursive (according to the standard model of computation, anyways). So a bit of circumlocution is needed.

That said, there is a positive result here. The key is the following lemma:

> Suppose $T$ is a computable subtree of $2^{<\mathbb{N}}$ (= the complete binary tree) which has a single infinite path $f$. Then $f$ is computable.

This may not seem relevant, but it applies to at least one version of your question. A bit roughly, if we have a finite set of tiles $X$ we can construe the set of partial $X$-tilings of the plane as a subtree $T_X$ of $2^{<\mathbb{N}}$. You write "I only care about sets with one unique sort of tessellation," and this corresponds to $T_X$ having a single infinite path. Consequently, in a precise sense we have:

> If a finite tileset can only tile the plane in a single way, that unique tiling is recursive.

Of course I'm skipping a fair amount of detail here, but the general thrust is accurate.